# Can an originating address (email) be tied to PHP / Swiftmailer?

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

My error:

`Uncaught exception 'Swift_BadResponseException' with message 'Expected response code(s) [250] but got response [550 Sender Rejected - MAIL FROM must be a valid domain.`

Could I have tied a sender-valid-domain to only one specific address?

I've had swiftmailer configured nicely and performing many operations for some months now. I honestly have no idea what happen, but my first hunch is that since the last time I used swiftmail and it worked correctly, I've installed bugzilla on the server.

The server has maNy virtual servers, and such I need multiple origination addresses.

I remember specifically skipping the mail configuration during the buzilla install, thinking I would come back to it. That was feb, and bugzilla has been used thoroughly since. Out of all the bugs added, only ONE added resulted in an email being sent (as bugzilla should, IF you configured the mail server, but I didn't so it was a puzzle to me).

So is there some way that my bugzilla install configured a specific address as the server's send address and now that I want to use a different domain Im causing the error?

Comment: Contact your MTA/mail server admin

Answer (score 0):

The fix was in the mx records...